# Would boiling distilled water in a kettle full of limescale increase the hardness of the water?

Tags: solubility

If I had a kettle which had limescale on it (due to several episodes of boiling hard water), and I would use it to boil distilled water, would that mean that some of the precipate dissolve into the distilled water, making that water harder than originally? If so, by how much?

I understand CaCO3 has very low solubility in normal conditions and requires CO2 to dissolve in higher amounts, but I'm not sure about how much is "low".

Comment: Yes, boiling distilled water in such a kettle would eventually dissolve any calcium carbonate deposit. Wikipedia lists the solubility as 0.013 g/L @25 C.

Comment: This still seems like a fairly low number? That would be only 5mg Ca. My tap water has around 130mg/L Ca. What about magnesium?

Comment: ...same result. Magnesium carbonate would eventually dissolve too.

Comment: If it precipitated _out_ of solution, it can go back _in_ to solution (barring a chemical reaction that makes it insoluble).

Comment: But if solubility of Ca is only 13mg/L, how come my tap water has 130mgCa/L ?

Comment: @CanGencer, you give the *anion* as Ca++ but what is the *cation*? Calcium bicarbonate,  Ca(HCO3)2,  is *far* more soluble, 16.6 g/100 ml. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table

Comment: Yes that's probably the solution in the water. However when it precipitates it precipates as CaCO3 if I'm right? So how could it dissolve back as Ca(HCO3)2?